problem with using algorithm2e after installing Texlive 2024
I installed texlive 2024 using this link on Ubuntu 2022.04 and added the latex folder to system paths I can compile the document when I do not use algorithm2e package. but unfortunately, when I want to use the \usepackage{algorithm2e} I get an error "File `algorithm2e.sty' not found. \newcommand" though I can find the "algorithm2e.sty" in "/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/algorithm2e/algorithm2e.sty". Could anyone help with this error?

check in your log file where latex finds article.cls and show this path.

Welcome to TeX.SE!

Thank you for your response In the log file when I search for "article.cls" I find this line "/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls"

and /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist is clearly a different path to /usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/. You have two tex systems.

I installed it on freshly installed Ubuntu though!

You can easily get the Ubunty texlive by installing an editor via the recommends feature.

How exactly did you add TeXLive 2024 to your PATH and how exactly are you compiling your document (via an editor? How do you start that editor?). Details matter here.

I added these line at the end of .bashrc file
TEXLIVE="/usr/local/texlive/2024/bin/x86_64-linux"
export PATH=$PATH:$TEXLIVE

I both tested texstudio for compiling and terminal but get the aforementioned error on the first command
"latex main.tex
pdflatex main.tex"

Does Texstudio install its latex files so it will be incompatible with Texlive 2024? because, after uninstalling Texstudio and compiling the tex file in the terminal, the problem was solved.
